# How to invoke functions on subsets of random samples of data

Tags: r

I'm trying to perform a t.test for a specific subset of data. Say I have a data set of 116 birds, and want to find a random sample of 35 birds (non-unique) of the "Species" category. I then want to find the mean of the "Body.Mass" of these random species. Then, I want to invoke a t.test on this sample as representative of the whole data.

I first stored the data in object "bird." I tried taking the random sample using sample(bird$Species, 35), which yielded 35 random species of bird. Now I can't seem to further subset this random sample to find the means of the Body.Mass of every random sample species. I tried to subset using tidyverse, but that's the only way I'm aware of to solve a problem like this.

```
library(dplyr)
bird = read.csv("NZBIRDS.csv")
dput(head(bird))
set.seed(20)
sambird = sample(bird$Species,35)
sambird

bmbird <- sambird %>% summarize(avg = mean(Body.Mass))
bmbird
```

```
structure(list(Species = c("Grebes", "Grebes", "Petrels", "Petrels", 
"Petrels", "Petrels"), Name = c("P. cristatus", "P. rufopectus", 
"P. gavia", "P. assimilis", "P. urinatrix", "P. georgicus"), 
Extinct = c("No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No"), Habitat = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), Nest.Site = c("G", "G", "GC", "GC", 
"GC", "GC"), Nest.Density = c("L", "L", "H", "H", "H", "H"
), Diet = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"), Flight = c("Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), Body.Mass = c(1100L, 
250L, 300L, 200L, 130L, 120L), Egg.Length = c(57, 43, 57, 
54, 38, 39)), .Names = c("Species", "Name", "Extinct", "Habitat", 
"Nest.Site", "Nest.Density", "Diet", "Flight", "Body.Mass", "Egg.Length"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Error in UseMethod("summarise_") : no applicable method for 'summarise_' applied to an object of class "factor"

Comment: bird = read.csv("NZBIRDS.csv",stringsAsFactors = F)

Comment: Please show some example data in your question so people can answer this more easily. At the moment `sambird` is just a vector of Species names, not a dataframe with multiple columns you can summarise. One solution might be to subset `bird` to just those rows that match one of the species in `sambird`.

Comment: @Marius Good point. Done.

Comment: Don't add data as an image. In R use `dput(head(df))` and copy the console output into the question. This makes is much easier for people to help (no one wants to transcribe your data into R). Also, you don't need to load the `tidyverse` package, `dplyr` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear whether you want to sample from a list of the *unique* species in the data, or sample rows so that each "Species" type can appear multiple times in the data. If you want to sample from the unique species, you can do:

```
# Only sampling one species since the example data
#   contains only two, should work fine
#   for more random species
random_species = sample(unique(bird$Species), 1, replace = FALSE)

bird %>%
    filter(Species %in% random_species) %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarize(avg = mean(Body.Mass))
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. The samples won't be unique, there will be 35 non-unique random species of bird from a data set of 116 birds for this particular problem, so there will be replacement

Comment: OK, you may have to explain further by providing some example output (what you want the final result of sampling to look like). We need to know which units are being sampled. The other issue is that your "Species" column looks more like "family" to me (not a biologist obviously), whereas your "Name" column seems to contain individual species. Are you sampling species or families?

Comment: I believe I got it. sambird = bird[sample(1:116,35), ] and then invoke: meanbird = apply(sambird[,"Body.Mass",drop=F],2,mean) to yield the sample mean of the 35 randomly chosen birds.